# How do I compare each element of a data frame column, to each item in a vector, In R?

Tags: r, vector, dataframe

I'm a beginner at R.
I want to remove all the rows of my data frame, where the column value of the row matches a value in the the vector. For example:

```
df = data.frame(A = c(a1, a2, a3), B = c(b1, b2, b3), C = c(c1, c2, c3))

vec = c("a43", "a2", "a7", ...)
```

So here row 2 should be removed because a2 from column A matches value a2 in vec (only column A is to be compared). How can I do this?

Edit: 
All relevant vectors are **character vectors**, if that makes a difference.
I have tried the following:
1. df1 = subset(df, !(df$A %in% vec))
2. df1 = subset(df, !(A %in% vec))
3. df1 = df[-which(df$A %in% vec),]
1. & 2. give me df1 = df2 , though there actually are a few matches.
3. gave me an empty dataframe in df1

Comment: I assume the variables A, B, and C are character vectors?

Comment: A, the vector in question, is a character vector, yes

Comment: You can try: `df[!(df$A %in% vec | df$B %in% vec | df$C %in% vec), ]`

Comment: Thanks for that Samuel, it works!